# Laravel get collection of models where relation has value

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I am trying to make a more elaborate registration form for my Laravel web app.
I have a `Category`, `Question` and `Survey` model.
A category `hasMany` `Question`'s and a `Question` `belongsTo` a `Survey`.

Category class:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}

public function getUsingAttribute()
{
    return $this->questions->contains('survey_id', Survey::current()->id);
}
```

I do currently have a `using` attribute in my Category class but I would like to make this a scope.
To be clear, the expected return of `Category::using->get()` would return all `Category` where at least one of the questions has a `survey_id` of `Survey::current()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it with one of the the methods available to [query a relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), specifically the `whereHas()` method:

```
return $this->whereHas('questions', function ($query){
    $query->where('survey_id', Survey::current());
});
```

Comment: I put this in a scope and changed the `$this` into `$query`, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
return $this->questions->where('survey_id', Survey::current()->id);
```