# Use Relationship in Laravel as a subquery to fetch result

Tags: php, laravel, orm, migration, relationship

This is causing me an error : ***where('like:is_liked',Auth::user()->id)***
In the stack trace says that 'is_liked' is not found in the event table.

```
 $events = Event::select('id', 'name', 'image', 'description', 'datetime', 'description', 'is_published')
            ->with('like:id,id_event,id_user,is_liked,created_at')
            ->with('like.user:id,name,surname')
            ->where('is_published', 1)->where('like:is_liked',Auth::user()->id)
            ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: If you want the event that the user likes: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298067/laravel-get-collection-of-models-where-relation-has-value/43298913, If you want all events with the likes from the user: like.is_liked instead of like:is_liked in your where statement

Comment: Can you give us the models for each of the tables - event, like, like.user ? Also have you tried to check what the actually query ran is? That info should be in the stack trace in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$events = Event::select('id', 'name', 'image', 'description', 'datetime', 'description', 'is_published')->with(['like'=>function($query) use ($user_id){
                $query->where('is_liked',$user_id);
              }])->where('is_published', 1)->paginate(6);
```

you can try like this

Comment: Please explain what the problem was and how your code solves it when answering